# SQL query to sum the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have my table data as follows

```
TaxTypeCode1   TaxTypeCode2  PNO   Amount 
-----------------------------------------
TX01           TX02           124     600
TX02           null           124     700 
TX03           TX04           124     200 
TX04           null           124     300
TX05           TX06           126     400 
TX06           null           127     500 
TX07           null           128     800
```

I would like to write SQL query to retrieve data.

Conditions apply IF pno is same and TaxTypeCode1 contain TaxTypeCode2 then sum the amt, otherwise display actual amt

My expected output is

```
PNO      Amount 
---------------
 124     1300
 124      500
 126      400
 127      500
 128      800
```

124 has 1300 because pno is same and TaxTypeCode2 (TX02) TaxTypeCode1 (TX02) are same then sum

```
TX01           (TX02)           124     600
(TX02)           null           124     700
```

126 has 400 because pno is different and TaxTypeCode2 (TX02) TaxTypeCode1 (TX02) are same don't sum

```
TX05           (TX06)           (126)     400 
(TX06)           null           (127)     500
```

Can anyone tell how to write query to retrieve that data?

Comment: This is not all that clear.  Is this a single table you're talking about?  Also, I would suggest putting a bit more effort into formatting the table.  Try including it in a code block, where you can separate the individual rows by line more clearly.

Comment: The GROUP BY statement is what you are looking for. Vutukuri has given the exact statement I would have used with the data you provided. I'm not sure what you were getting at with the TaxTypes, but grouping on your PNO's alone would give you the desired outcome. It might be that within your actual data, PNO is all you need to consider?

Comment: Will you ever have a case where Record A will have a TaxCodeType2 that will match Record B's TaxCodeType1 and Record B's TaxCodeType2 will not be null? If so, do you need to keep linking records based on that link?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT PNO,SUM(Amount)
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY PNO;
```

Comment: situations like this, it will be better if we see what the person has tried for us to help him/her...thats the only way they can learn

Comment: TaxTypeCode1   TaxTypeCode2  PNO   Amount  
TX01           TX02           124     600 
TX02           null           124     700  
TX03           TX04           124     200  
TX04           null           124     300 
TX05           TX06           126     400  
TX06           null           127     500  
TX07           null           128     800 then  out put will be

Comment: PNO      Amount  
 124     1300 
 124     500 
 126     400 
 127     500 
 128     800

Comment: Can you post your question by editing the existing one.It doesn't make any sense to me what you posted..

Answer (score 2):

This is your table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    TaxTypeCode1 CHAR(4),
    TaxTypeCode2 CHAR(4),
    PNO INT,
    Amount INT
)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX01', 'TX02', 124, 600)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX02', null, 124, 700)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX03', 'TX04', 124, 200)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX04', null, 124, 300)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX05', 'TX06', 126, 400)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX06', null, 127,500)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('TX07', null, 128, 800)
```

and this is query for you:

```
SELECT PNO, SUM(Amount)
FROM Test
GROUP BY PNO, COALESCE(TaxTypeCode2, TaxTypeCode1)
```

Result matches your expected output.

I found that you really do is aggregating data by PNO and by second or first column (if second is empty). `COALESCE(TaxTypeCode2, TaxTypeCode1)` will return first not empty.

You can also use `ISNULL(TaxTypeCode2, TaxTypeCode1)`. `COALESCE` can have more than 2 params like `COALESCE(TaxTypeCode3, TaxTypeCode2, TaxTypeCode1)`.

See that:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TaxTypeCode2, TaxTypeCode1) as sumBy, * FROM Test
```