# How to take sum of column with same id in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql query to sum the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142367/sql-query-to-sum-the-data)

I have following table structure

```
TradeId     TableName        PricingSecurityID  Quantity    Price   
2008        Fireball.dbo.Bond    506             50         100.0000    
2009        Fireball.dbo.Bond    506             50         100.2500    
2010        Fireball.dbo.Bond    588             50         100.7500    
2338        Fireball.dbo.Bond    588             100        102.5000
```

I need to take a sum of `Quantity` of matching or we can say group by particular `PricingSecurityID`

like for `PricingSecurityID=506` I should get `quantity=100`

and for `PricingSecurityID=588` I should get `quantity=150`

How can I write this SQL query?

> I did try with simple group by statement
>   but as i'm also selecting tradeid i'm getting error :
>   Column 'TradeId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It's a rudimentary aggregate `SUM(Quantity) GROUP BY PricingSecurityID`. Do you need other columns along with it, or just the Quantity?

Comment: Three equal answers. I'd suggest to delete the second and third one, for the sake of a cleaner stackoverflow. It's up to the posters though.

Comment: updated question not that much simple friends plz help\

Comment: It is not clear what is the expected result. For example which value of `tradeId` should be along with `PricingSecurityID=506` ?

Comment: @ashuthinks You are wrong. You say for PricingSecurityId=506 the sum should be 100, but then  what TradeId should you see with this 100? 2008 or 2009? Please elaborate more showing us the full result set you expect from, say, PricingSecurityID=506.

Comment: no only associated PricingSecurityID not tradeid needed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Revised question — the TradeID is also needed.

```
SELECT f.TradeID, f.PricingSecurityID, s.TotalQuantity
  FROM FollowingTableStructure AS f
  JOIN (SELECT PricingSecurityID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
          FROM FollowingTableStructure
         GROUP BY PricingSecurityId
       ) AS s ON f.PricingSecurityID = s.PricingSecurityID
```

I'm not wholly convinced the query is sensible, but that's your problem.  It can easily be extended to deal with other tables; just add appropriate JOIN clauses.

---

*Please remember to include a table name in the question — it is astonishing how often SQL questions are asked without giving the table a name (so it is not only you who forgets by any means).*

---

Re-updated question

So the originally anonymous table is, apparently, `Fireball.dbo.Trade` or `Fireball..Trade`.  I'd probably place the 11-way UNION into a view since it is likely to be used in multiple places.  However, ignoring that, we can still slip the information into your query:

```
SELECT t.TradeId, 
       ISNULL(Securities.SecurityType,'Other') SecurityType, 
       Securities.TableName,
       CASE 
       WHEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId IS NOT NULL THEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId
       ELSE Trade.SecurityId
       END AS PricingSecurityID,
       s.TotalQuantity AS Quantity,
       t.Price,
       CASE
       WHEN (t.Buy = 1 AND t.Long = 1) THEN 1
       WHEN (t.Buy = 0 AND t.Long = 0) THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS Position
  FROM Fireball_Reporting..Trade AS t
  JOIN (SELECT PricingSecurityID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
          FROM Fireball_Reporting..Trade
         GROUP BY PricingSecurityId
       ) AS s ON t.PricingSecurityID = s.PricingSecurityID
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT TradeId, 'Bond' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Bond' TableName FROM Fireball..CorpBondTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'IRS' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Bond' TableName FROM Fireball..IRPTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Treasury' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Bond' TableName FROM Fireball..TreasuryTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Index' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.CDSIndex' TableName FROM Fireball..CreditIndexTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'CDS' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.CDS' TableName FROM Fireball..CDSTrade WHERE IsSovereign = 0
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Sovereign CDS' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.CDS' TableName FROM Fireball..CDSTrade WHERE IsSovereign = 1
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Equity Option' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.EquityOption' TableName FROM Fireball..EquityOptionTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Equity' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Equity' TableName FROM Fireball..EquityTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Loan' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Loan' TableName FROM Fireball..LoanTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Swaption' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Bond' TableName FROM Fireball..SwaptionTrade
        UNION
        SELECT TradeId, 'Preferred Stock' SecurityType, 'Fireball.dbo.Bond' TableName FROM Fireball..PreferredEquityTrade
        --UNION
        --SELECT TradeId, 'Bond' SecurityType FROM Fireball..BondTrade
       ) AS Securities ON Securities.TradeId = t.TradeId
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT TradeID, SecurityId 
          FROM Fireball..CDSTrade 
        UNION
        SELECT TradeID, SecurityId 
         FROM Fireball..CreditIndexTrade          
       ) AS SecurityTrade ON SecurityTrade.TradeId = t.TradeId
```

That's mostly copy and paste — with some reformatting — of your query, with the extra sub-query tucked away in the FROM clause after the Trade table.  Were it my query, I'd be using single-letter (or other short mnemonic) aliases for the last two sub-queries too; I just didn't spend the time working out what were appropriate abbreviations for SecurityTrade and Securities.

Answer (score 13):

```
select PricingSecurityID, sum(Quantity)
from table
group by PricingSecurityID
```

Comment: Thank you! This is nice and short!

Answer (score 12):

```
select PricingSecurityID, sum(quantity)
from Fireball.dbo.Bond
group by PricingSecurityID
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT PricingSecurityID, SUM(ISNULL(Quantity,0))
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY PricingSecurityId;
```

Comment: `ISNULL` isn't necessary here; any values that are null won't be included, and the `SUM` will be the same.

Comment: updated question not that much simple friends plz help\ thanks

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: It's common to have `ISNULL(SUM(Quantity),0)` though in case there are only nulls in the column (for a group).