# Cumulative Sum in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have query (below) that show me data in the column "Monthly".

[image: Result]

but I need to rewrite this query to cumulative sums as shows third column on picture.
How can I do it? 
Thanks for any reply.

My current query:

```
select cast( ( Prodej.Ce_Jedn * Prodej.Mnoz ) / 1000 as numeric(15,2) ) as "Monthly" ,
       YEAR(  FAV.vatDate ) as "Rok" ,
       month( FAV.VatDate ) as "Měsíc" 
from Prodej
join FAKTVYDA FAV on FAV.Ci   = PRODEJ.C_Fak
                 and FAV.Rada = PRODEJ.R_Fak
where YEAR(FAV.VATDate) > year(getdate())-3
  and FAV.Rada in ('10','20','30','60') 
  and PRODEJ.C_Fak <> 0
  and '@{Stredisko.ParameterValue}' = case Prodej.Str 
                                        when ''  then FAV.Str
                                        when '-' then FAV.Str 
                                        else     Prodej.str
                                      end
order by month(FAV.VatDate)
```

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate running total / running balance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance)

Comment: See this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server There's more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a SUM-statement, the query also requires a GROUP BY-statement.
This is not included in the query above, so it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by using a SUM statement in front of the field you want summarized. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864467/how-to-take-sum-of-column-with-same-id-in-sql) post which provides a solution that should fit your problem.

```
select cast( ( Prodej.Ce_Jedn * Prodej.Mnoz ) / 1000 as numeric(15,2) ) as "Monthly" ,
YEAR(  FAV.vatDate ) as "Rok" ,
month( FAV.VatDate ) as "Měsíc" 
SUM(( Prodej.Ce_Jedn * Prodej.Mnoz ) / 1000 as numeric(15,2) ) as "Cumulative"
from Prodej
join FAKTVYDA FAV on FAV.Ci   = PRODEJ.C_Fak
and FAV.Rada = PRODEJ.R_Fak
where YEAR(FAV.VATDate) > year(getdate())-3
and FAV.Rada in ('10','20','30','60') 
and PRODEJ.C_Fak <> 0
and '@{Stredisko.ParameterValue}' = case Prodej.Str 
when ''  then FAV.Str
when '-' then FAV.Str 
else     Prodej.str
end
order by month(FAV.VatDate)
```

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Possibly because it resembles a link-only answer?  (I didn't down vote you.)  You may wish to [edit] your answer and add some additional details.  Just a thought.

Comment: Pretty lame in my book, none of the other answers are any different.

Comment: Maybe be a member for longer than 10 days before deciding whether something here is lame or not. Please read [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to get at least some background on why a link to another web site or a low-quality duplicate is not desirable.