# How to Sum the amount and query the highest amount user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the record in table as follow;

```
no. name  amount
1.  joh   100
2.  cathy 100
3.  phyo  300
4.  phyo  100
5.  joh   100
6.  cathy 50
```

I would like to sum the amount of each name and query the highest user with amount.
How to make these query in mysql.

Comment: i mean how to write a query to get the highest amount user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as total FROM user_amounts GROUP BY name ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```

Explanation:

I'll explain how you should write your queries, or at least how to solve next time.

First start with a  simple select of names and amounts:

```
SELECT name, amount FROM user_amounts
```

Then we want to know amount of every name, so we have this query:

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as total FROM user_amounts GROUP BY name
```

As you can see i used `SUM` function and `GROUP BY` because if you don't use `GROUP BY name` then your result will be only one row.

After that we have something like this

```
joh   200
cathy 150
phyo  400
```

But we want the first the higher ammouunt, so need to order it, and we only want the higher, so limit 1 to only recover the first name

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as total FROM user_amounts GROUP BY name ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope it'll be clear.

Comment: @Strawberry Added some explanation

Comment: I think our definitions of 'highest' and 'lowest' differ. Rest assured, if you worked for me, I'd make sure you had the 'highest' salary in the office!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
But this will have issues with you have a tie.

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as total
 FROM user_amounts 
GROUP BY name ORDER BY 2 desc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two parts - 1) At first need to sum individual user data 2) find out highest data. check this question with answer [SQL query to sum the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142367/sql-query-to-sum-the-data), you will get idea for doing it. use `select name, sum(amount) as total from table group by name order by total DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as total FROM user_amounts GROUP BY name ORDER BY total SUM(Marks) DESC LIMIT 1
```