# Sum 2 columns where values are same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will start with the table:
[image]
Query:

```
SELECT taw.user_id AS taw_user_id, COALESCE(SUM(tai.bid), 0) AS tai_bid, taw.win AS taw_win
FROM tb_auction_winners taw JOIN
     tb_aukciono_istorija tai
     ON taw.id = tai.aukciono_id
WHERE tai.user_id = 206 AND taw.user_id = 206
GROUP BY aukciono_id, taw.user_id;
```

My problem is that I cannot get my desired result (changed using inspect element):
[image]

It should sum all `tai_bid` and `taw_win` values where `taw_user_id` is same. I have read [SQL query to sum the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142367/sql-query-to-sum-the-data) and [How to take sum of column with same id in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864467/how-to-take-sum-of-column-with-same-id-in-sql) threads but it did not help. Using `GROUP BY aukciono_id, taw_user_id` everything should be fine but it does not work. I guess it is a very easy fix but I cannot find what is wrong :( Help me, please.

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6945a/1

Comment: Selecting `taw.win` doesn't make sense in the context of your `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got it right: you just want to sum by taw_user_id - so thats the only column in the GROUP BY clause

```
  SELECT taw.user_id AS taw_user_id
      ,SUM(taw.win) AS taw_win
      ,SUM(tai.bid) AS tai_bid
  FROM tb_auction_winners taw
  INNER JOIN  
  ( SELECT aukciono_id, user_id, SUM(bid) as bid
      FROM tb_aukciono_istorija
      group by aukciono_id, user_id
   )  tai
  ON taw.id = tai.aukciono_id
  AND taw.user_id  = tai.user_id
 WHERE taw.user_id = 206 
 GROUP BY taw.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have tried that, I don't know why but it doesn't return what I want. http://imgur.com/fvu7QSz

Comment: could you explain it more exactly please? would be easier to help
what do you expect exactly?
what do you receive currently?

Maybe you can create a little SQLFiddle
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464/what-is-sqlfiddle-and-why-should-i-care

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis: now i got it - i just updated my answer above

through the join the rows doubled before. thats why i aggregate the data from tb_aukciono_istorija by aukciono_id and user_id, before joining with data from tb_auction_winners

Answer (score 2):

Check this Query

```
   select taw_user_id,sum(taw_win) as taw_win,sum(tai_bid) as tai_bid from
    (
    select taw.user_id AS taw_user_id,sum(win) as taw_win ,(select sum(bid) from tb_aukciono_istorija
    where user_id=taw.user_id and taw.id =aukciono_id ) AS tai_bid from tb_auction_winners   taw where user_id=206
    group by  taw.id)   temp
```

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6945a/86

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but I already checked one :)